# Overwrite auto generated css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a Jquery wysiwyg editor which at runtime automatically adds code to the textarea.

My problem is that it's inserting an inline style of style="width:320px" and I need to take that off as I've already set the styles to make it go 100%

Is there anyway to remove or overwrite that code with jquery

It's basically adding an inline style to a div with a class called wysiwyg...

so:

```
<div class="wysiwyg" style="width:320px">
```

The editor I'm having the trouble with is called: jWYSIWYG

Here's a demo url: http://akzhan.github.com/jwysiwyg/help/examples/

Comment: Off course there is but it is kind of hard to help you without seeing the html produced by the wysiwyg editor.

Comment: Why not just look in the code for this value and change it?

Comment: You might want to tell which editor it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to override inline styles you have two options:

Pure CSS:

```
.wysiwyg {
    width: 120px !important;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(".wysiwyg").css({width:120});
```

If you want to use styles from somewhere else you can also do:

```
$(".wysiwyg").css({width:"inherit"});
```

Comment: Note that `.css({width:120})` is equivalent to `.css('width', 120)`.

Answer (score 1):

Reset the `width` using jQuery:

```
$('.wysiwyg').css('width', '100%');
```

Alternatively, you could remove the `style` attribute altogether:

```
$('.wysiwyg').removeAttr('style');
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried declaring your own CSS with:

```
!important
```

eg.

```
#textarea-id { width: 300px !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either define a new css rule with !important, or use jquery:

```
$("rule target").width(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
$('.wysiwyg').removeAttr("style");
```

or alternatively you can set the width to 100%

```
$('.wysiwyg').css("width", "100%");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove undesired attributes on server-side with `removeAttribute()` DOM-method if you have server-side DOM manipulation module.

Or you can try to create your own slightly modified version of your WYSIWYG JS module.